# Specify a background image via CSS in Vaadin 14 programmatically with Java

Tags: css, background-image, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In Vaadin 14, we can set some CSS values programmatically in our Java code.

We can call [`getElement`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.10/com/vaadin/flow/component/HasElement.html#getElement--), then [`getStyle`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.10/com/vaadin/flow/dom/Element.html#getStyle--), and set the name of the CSS property along with a value.

For example, here we set the background color to green.

```
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout
{
    public MainView ( )
    {
        this.getElement().getStyle().set( "background-color" , "Green" );
```

How do we do this for a CSS property like [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) that takes an argument of the CSS function named `url`?

Hard-coding the CSS path does not work.

```
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout
{
    public MainView ( )
    {
        this.getElement().getStyle().set( "background-image" , "cat.jpg" );
```

➥ In Vaadin Flow, how to do we use Java to get CSS to find an image such as `"cat.jpg"`?

Furthermore, what should be the relative or absolute path to that image file be? I understand that the usual place for static images in Vaadin web app is in the `src/main/resources` folder.

Comment: `"url(MamaCat.jpg)"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of a "Plain Java Servlet" (non-[Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework), non-[CDI](http://cdi-spec.org)) Vaadin project, the file should go under `/src/main/webapp`

In case of Spring: `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/img`

Taken from official docs here: [Resource Cheat Sheet](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/importing-dependencies/tutorial-ways-of-importing.html#resource-cheat-sheet)

And, as @symlink has noticed in the comments, you should use a `url('filename')` syntax to reference an image in css : [CSS background-image Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

For example, if I have a file named `cat.jpg` inside a `/src/main/webapp/images`, then this sets it `getElement().getStyle().set("background-image","url('images/cat.jpg')");`

---

Here is another example, with the picture file `cat.jpg` in `src/main/webapp` without nesting in an `images` folder. This is a Vaadin 14.0.10 web app, using the `Plain Java Servlet` technology stack option on the [*Start a new project with Vaadin*](https://vaadin.com/start/latest) page.

[image: screenshot of file "cat.jpg" in project folder src/main/webapp.]

Below is the source code for an entire view using this image as a background.

Notice the first line of the constructor, where we pass `"url('cat.jpg')"` as an argument. See how we used single-quote marks around the file name to embed in a Java string without escaping. Fortunately the CSS specification allows for either single quotes (') or double quotes (") — quite convenient for Vaadin programmers embedding CSS within Java code.

```
package work.basil.example;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;

/**
 * The main view contains a button and a click listener.
 */
@Route ( "" )
@PWA ( name = "Project Base for Vaadin", shortName = "Project Base" )
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout
{
    public MainView ( )
    {
        this.getElement().getStyle().set( "background-image" , "url('cat.jpg')" );

        Button button = new Button( "Click me" , event -> Notification.show( "Clicked!" ) );
        add( button );
    }
}
```

And a screenshot of this web app in action. The image is cropped because of the short height of the `VerticalLayout`. The layout is short because it contains only a button, whose label `Click me` can be seen faintly in blue text on the left edge. The cropped cat’s face is repeated across the page as is the default with CSS.

[image: screenshot of Vaadin 14.0.10 web app with cat picture used in background]